# Haskell - Could not deduce (Num Bool) arising from the literal `0'

Tags: haskell, boolean, ghci

My program is suposed to sum the number of students with a grade above 9 (from 0 to 20), from an input like this:

```
aprov [("John",14)("Martha",8)("Elsa",12)]
```

The output should be "2". But while compiling it:

```
k = 0
aprov [] = 0
aprov ((a,n):y)  = if n > 9 then k == k + 1 else k == k
```

GHCi gives me this error:

```
Could not deduce (Num Bool) arising from the literal `0'
from the context (Num a, Ord a)
  bound by the inferred type of
     aprov :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(t, a)] -> Bool
  at prog.hs:(29,1)-(30,55)
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Bool)
In the expression: 0
In an equation for `aprov': aprov [] = 0
```

What can I do to fix it. And by the way is how can I limitate the "n" so that the maximium is 20?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you specify

```
aprov [] = 0
```

And then on the next line you say

```
aprov ((a,n):y) = if n > 9 then k == k + 1 else k == k
```

Which returns one of the two expressions

```
k == k + 1
```

Or

```
k == k
```

Which are booleans.  So the compiler thinks that your function *has* to return a `Bool`, but you also have it return `0`, which is a `Num a => a`, and `Bool` is not a `Num`.

---

You say that you want to count the students whose grade passes a particular test, in this case `(>9)`.  Well, in Haskell all values are immutable, you can't change them from their initial values.  This is hard at first, we're used to being able to modify variables, but in Haskell *there are no variables*.

Instead, we can use functions to perform the operations we would normally use variables for.  So let's list the problem statement and the steps we can take to get there:

> Count the number of students with a grade above 9

We can solve this with the steps:

1. Find the students with a grade above 9
2. Count the number of those students.

Let's solve the first step:

```
-- A simple type alias to make our type signatures more readable
-- This just says that "Student" and "(String, Int)" are interchangeable
type Student = (String, Int)

withMinGrade :: Int -> [Student] -> [Student]
withMinGrade minGrade [] = []
withMinGrade minGrade ((name, grade):rest) =
    if grade > minGrade
        then (name, grade) : withMinGrade minGrade rest
        else                 withMinGrade minGrade rest
```

So here we say that if we ask for which students have a minimum grade from an empty list, we get an empty list back.  If there's at least one student in the list, we check their grade against the minimum allowed, and if it's greater than we return it along with the performing the same operation on the rest of the students, otherwise we just check the rest of the students.  If this seems like a lot of work, it's because it is!  Haskell comes with a handy function built-in for performing this exact operation called `filter`.  It looks like

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter condition [] = []
filter condition (x:xs) =
    if condition x    -- Apply the function "condition" to "x" returning a Bool
        then x : filter condition xs
        else     filter condition xs
```

Notice how this is basically the same as `withMinGrade`, but generalized to any condition.  Using `filter`, we can implement `withMinGrade` much more simply:

```
withMinGrade :: Int -> [Student] -> [Student]
withMinGrade minGrade students = filter checkStudent students
    where checkStudent (name, grade) = grade > minGrade
```

We could also do this with a lambda function inline so we don't have to define `checkStudent`:

```
withMinGrade minGrade students = filter (\(name, grade) -> grade > minGrade) students
```

Or even with some fun function composition:

```
withMinGrade minGrade students = filter ((> minGrade) . snd) students
```

I'll let you play with this definition to figure out how it works

---

Now to solve problem 2.  This one uses a similar style of recursion, but we return a number instead of a list:

```
-- count should work on any kind of list
count :: [a] -> Int
count [] = 0
```

So that case is easy, an empty list has 0 elements in it.  What about a list that has at least one element?  Well, intuitively, we'd want it to return a count 1 greater than the length of the rest of the list, or with code

```
count :: [a] -> Int
count [] = 0
count (x:xs) = 1 + count xs
```

So very simply, we say that the number of elements in a list is just 1 more than the number of elements in the tail of the list.  Again, Haskell has a built in function for this (that's more efficient) called `length` that we can use instead!  It's a drop in replacement for `count`.

---

So wrapping up, we can combine these two functions, `withMinGrade` and `length`, to write our desired function, but I'll leave that step as homework.  Since this is your first Haskell program, I'll also direct you towards [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), the very easy-to-read book I used to get started with this fun and powerful language.  It'll show you many examples and give lots of explanations of how Haskell works, and how you can do general programming without ever needing to modify a variable again!  It's difficult to "get" at first, but once you embrace immutability, you'll wish you had it in C/C++/Python/Java/.NET/Ruby/Bash/Javascript/etc.  It really makes it easier to understand how code works and be sure that it will always work that way every single time.

Comment: so, how can I fix it? please explain me because this is one of my first programs...

Comment: @magamig I'm writing up more right now, give me a few minutes and I'll have some updates =)